# How JSOM works in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, csom, jsom

I know how CSOM works in SharePoint but am not aware of JSOM. Kindly elaborate how it works in SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

`JSOM` in SharePoint stands for `JavaScript Object Model`. Its is similar to CSOM i.e. C# Object Model. Actually you'll find lots of similarities b/w these two OM. Like CSOM, in order to run JSOM you require two JS scripts i.e. `SP.js` and `SP.runtime.js`. All these scripts file needs to be added on SharePoint page using `Content Editor WP` or `Script Editor WP`.

All the steps are common in CSOM and JSOM like `creating the client context`, `loading the object` (using clientContext.load method). But in CSOM you have `executeQuery` which is synchronous function is not available in JSOM, instead we have `executeQueryAsyn` function which does the same job but in asynchronous manner.

Follow the URL to learn more on JSOM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint